# Laravel 5 google mail smtp issue

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 for sending mail using google smtp. in my env file i set

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME={user}
MAIL_PASSWORD={pass}
```

and in my route

```
get('sendemail', function () {
    $data = array(
        'name' => "Learning Laravel",
    );
    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
        $message->from('alam.ifta@gmail.com', 'Learning Laravel');
        $message->to('ifta123@gmail.com','Bappa')->subject('Learning Laravel test email');
    });
    return "Your email has been sent successfully";
});
```

it send email successfully, but in my inbox i see that the sender is not `alam.ifta@gmail.com` but from that account which i use in `.env` file. Where is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: if you want your email to show as sender, then just use it in the .env file with your gmail password.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail does not let modify the address your emails come from. It's intended for personal use, not a server's outgoing mail.

If you want that, you need to use an email service designed for sending such emails. Laravel supports many of them out-of-the-box like Mailgun, Mandrill, and Amazon SES. Each has a generous free tier.